# Avoid WPF statusbar gets totally collapsed when window gets resized vertically to a smaller size

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, statusbar

I have below WPF window which contains a dockpanel as main container. Then I place a main grid at the top (which contains some other grids) and a statusbar at the bottom.

```
<Window>

  <DockPanel>
     <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
         <!-- Grid stuff here -->
     </Grid>

     <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"                   
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

            <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Text="Item1"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="1" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="3" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="4">
                <TextBlock Text="AnotherItem" />
            </StatusBarItem>
  </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

I have below problem:
When window is resized vertically to a smaller size, there comes a moment in which statusbar height is reduced and even completely collapsed. So how to avoid this? I want statusbar never gets collapsed and keep all the time its height.

Comment: Use a Grid as the root of the view, put the status bar in row 1 with a height of auto and put the other grid in row 0 with a height of *

Comment: @Will Thanks, it works!

Comment: Well, hell, I thought you'd have issues with that. Okay, I'll jot down an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

Grids within Grids are so hot right now.

```
<Window x:Class="GridRoot.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10" Background="CornflowerBlue">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    Hello!
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="1">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock>
                    GET OFF ME!
                </TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The top row takes up as much space is available, and the bottom row takes up as much space as its content desires. Since the StatusBar control pretty much has a set height, it will always stay visible on the bottom.

Some folks might have issue with putting a Grid inside another Grid, but there's absolutely no reason not to.

The above example, tiny
[image: Tiny version of the window]

and embiggened
[image: Large version of the window]